# Get a random record from database/entity using CI2 + Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

The following would return the a random record with Doctrine:

```
$name = Doctrine::getTable('nametable')
->createQuery()
->select('name')
->orderBy('RAND()')
->fetchOne();
```

But I'm running CI2 + Doctrine2, and so it does not work `Call to undefined method Doctrine::getTable()`

I've tried

```
$data = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('ORM\Project\Names')
                 ->orderBy('RAND()')
                 ->fetchOne();
```

But this does not work either:  `Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Undefined method 'orderBy'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!'`

Perhaps findOneBy is what I want, but it expects an array.

Is there an elegant way to fetch a random record in this setup?

**Edit:**

This is what I've come up with:

```
$query = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("select max(u.id) from ORM\Dynasties2\Femalenames u");
$result = $query->getSingleResult();
$highval = $result[1];
$random_name = rand(1,$highval);
$name = $this->doctrine->em->find('ORM\Dynasties2\Femalenames', $random_name);
$mother_name = $name->getName();
```

Surely there is a cleaner way???   Apparently there's no such thing as RAND() in CI2/Doctrine2, short of just writing a SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've come up with:

```
$query = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("select max(u.id) from ORM\Dynasties2\Femalenames u");
$result = $query->getSingleResult();
$highval = $result[1];
$random_name = rand(1,$highval);
$name = $this->doctrine->em->find('ORM\Dynasties2\Femalenames', $random_name);
$mother_name = $name->getName();
```

I assumed there was another way, but cannot discover it.

Comment: Yes, that's the doctrine way of handling it. You can also use a function like this: https://gist.github.com/Thinkscape/124d658e4076421c0516

Answer (score 1):

**"orderBy"** is not working when you try to access the repository. In this case you have to make a query with "createQuery" or the query builder **"createQueryBuilder"**.

**The other way is:**

```
$data = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('ORM\Project\Names')->findOneBy(array(
    'field' => 'ASC or DESC'
));
```

Here you can test RAND instead ASC or DESC but i think the best way is to make a query.

You can define a function in your repository and make a query that you have all querys in your repo and not in your controller then your first example looks good.